# Autohotkey script doesn't work only in Skype

Tags: autohotkey

I am using this AutoHotKey script that presses `ALT+SHIFT` when I am pressing `RSHIFT` (to change the keyboard layout).

It works great everywhere, except Skype.

In Skype it doesn't change the keyboard layout. Manually pressing the same button (`ALT`+`SHIFT`) would work.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Skype is running with higher user permissions than AutoHotkey is? AHK can't send simulated input to programs that have higher permissions than it does, presumably to prevent permission elevation exploits. If this is the problem, running the script as administrator would fix it.